# Google Amp with Reactjs Webapplication

Tags: reactjs, single-page-application, amp-html

We have react App with node. I want to convert only one page to AMP. I am confused. I can't figure out from where to start!
I have read so much about amp with react but do not found any proper example of amp with react.
I want to convert only one component to amp how should I proceed? Any help will be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That will not be so simple. AMP does not allow loading custom javascript.
You will need to server-side render that single page, and not hydrate the javascript on the front end. So the page will be basically static. which begs the question - why do you want to do that with React?

Another way to do that is to render one that one page using node (express for example), and use another route for your single page application.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I am generating that one page (which I want to convert in AMP) dynamically for example when I am clicking any article from article list I am navigating to article detail page according to id of that article.So do you mean that I have to implement separate route for article detail page? And if possible can you share example of the server side rendering?

Comment: Actually you  can load custom JavaScript with `amp-script`.